# How to identify meaning of a key word used in a var name

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, data-modeling

I have a list of variable names and their definitions. What I want is a list of key words used in Variable names with their meaning automatically getting pulled from the definition. Can someone please suggest me an approach for this problem and the possible algorithm that can be used. I am new to machine learning and modelling.

Example:
**Var Name**: LGL_RESTR_IND

**Definition**: Indicates whether an account is subject to a legal restriction and the account holder cannot withdraw or transfer security and dollar assets out of the account.

Here LGL represents Legal, RESTR represents restriction and IND represents indicator.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just create a map/dict of `Var Name` to its `Definition`?

Comment: This is my first project and i want to use some advance analytics technique so that I can get some hands-on experience on it.